# How can i access android global variable from java class

Tags: android

I need to access android global(Application) variable from java class which is inside the my application.I tried with using Context ,but unable.Is there a way to do this ?
Below is the my Application class.I am adding some values for jsonUrl inside my activity.So i need to access these values from a java class.

```
public class Application extends Application {


    private static String jsonUrl;


    public static String getJsonUrl() {
        return jsonUrl;
    }

    public static void setJsonUrl(String jsonUrl) {
        SPHApplication.jsonUrl = jsonUrl;
    }
```

}

Then i tried to get this valus using below code in my java class.

Application.getJsonUrl();

But it doesn't give me the valus?

Comment: Can you brief more about your requirement? With example or so.

Comment: post some code to get clear idea

Comment: Use static variable? Or make Application class singleton?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

You could use a static variable by using the `static` keyword. Then, by using `MyClass.staticVariable`, you can access it.

Another way is to subclass the `android.app.Application` class and store your variables there. Then, retrieve them whenever you need.

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/how-to-declare-global-variables-in-android?rq=1)